# How to implement GPS tracking cheaply

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, gps

What would be the most practical and cheap way for me to implement a GPS tracker in an ebike I'm working on, so that I could track it on my phone or an online service in case it is stolen or displaced. I am very interested in developing myself a working system like this!

Comment: buy a GPS tracker. Quicker and cheaper than trying to develop one yourself.

Comment: This is like saying I want to listen to music, how do I build an MP3 player? Or I want to go sailing, how do I build a boat? These types of questions are too big for this site to handle, we can only write so much.

Comment: You can buy GPS trackers from China via ebay or eg www.aliexpress.com for from $US10 or so up to much more. You cannot build one as cheaply using even modules. I'd recommend that you look at internet discussions and find one that others say meets the need. OR many cheap cellphones can be set up to do this. Concealment and powering are probably the main issues.

Comment: @laptop2d I can refer you to a DIY MP3 player build :-) -  a little long in the tooth now.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon on this site? probably from the chiphacker days?

Comment: @laptop2d Bob Blick of PICLIst and elsewhere fame.

Comment: @Elliot W - [**Ali Express GPS trackers**](https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?ltype=wholesale&d=y&origin=y&isViewCP=y&catId=0&initiative_id=SB_20170316035909&SearchText=gps+tracker&blanktest=0&tc=af) Caveat Emptor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at this point just buy one of the dog trackers for $60, I dont think you are going to make one cheaper.  Unless you buy a cheap/used smart phone and activate it and leave it with the bike.

If you want to do it yourself you will need a gps receiver, pretty cheap like $10 on ebay.  Super easy to parse the NMEA data.  You will need some sort of processor, a microcontroller will do, or a raspberry pi zero or something like that.  You will need power.  And if you want to track it with your phone you will need a cellular module, that is going to cost several times the cost of a used phone.  YOu might find some on ebay, but note they are not necessarily what you think they are.  Adafruit has one, you will need a sim card and service for it.  And then work out how to talk to it, for texting or other such things it is not too bad, there are libraries.

You are better off activating a cheap or used phone and running an app and keeping it charged.